# ROS no message published on a topic when I played a rosbag

Tags: ros

I'm trying to create a rosbag from my own image(RGB-D) and IMU data by using code like this:

```
        sensor_msgs::ImagePtr ros_rgb_msg;
        ros_rgb_msg = imgrgb.toImageMsg();
        ros_rgb_msg->header.seq = iFrame;
        ros_rgb_msg->header.stamp = stamp;
        ros_rgb_msg->header.frame_id = iFrame;
        bag.write("cam0/image_raw", stamp,ros_rgb_msg);

        sensor_msgs::ImagePtr ros_depth_msg;
        ros_depth_msg = imgdepth.toImageMsg();
        ros_depth_msg->header.seq = iFrame;
        ros_depth_msg->header.stamp = stamp;
        ros_depth_msg->header.frame_id = iFrame;
        bag.write("cam0/depth", stamp, ros_depth_msg);

        sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
        imu_msg.header.stamp = stamp;
        imu_msg.header.seq = iFrame;
        imu_msg.header.frame_id = "imu";
        imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = tmpgyros.data[0];
        imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = tmpgyros.data[1];
        imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = tmpgyros.data[2];
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = tmpacc.data[0];
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = tmpacc.data[1];
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = tmpacc.data[2];

        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[0] = 0.001f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[1] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[2] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[3] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[4] = 0.001f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[5] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[6] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[7] = 0.0f;
        imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[8] = 0.001f;
        imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance = imu_msg.orientation_covariance =imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance;
        bag.write("/imu0", stamp, imu_msg);
```

where iFrame is an `int` representing that the iFrame-th image is being written into the bag, the beginning six lines of the code write the RGB part into the bag and publish them on `cam0/image_raw`, the next six lines write the depth part into the bag and publish them on `cam0/depth`

Then I try to use the generated bag as the input for VINS, in `feature_tracker_node.cpp`, I modified the subscriber as below

```
ros::Subscriber sub_img = n.subscribe("cam0/image_raw", 100, img_callback);
```

However, when I first run `roslaunch vins_estimator euroc.launch` then run`rosbag play mytest.bag` in two different terminals, I use `rostopic hz cam0/image_raw` to watch the message on the node, but it shows no message is published on this node while both of the two terminals are running. And the callback function in `feature_tracker_node.cpp` ,that is ,`void img_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &img_msg)` is never called.

But when I watch `imu0`,it works perfectly, many messages are published on this topic.

I also used

```
        cv_bridge::CvImageConstPtr ptr1;
        ptr1 = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(ros_rgb_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8);
        cv::imshow("test bag1",ptr1->image);
        cv::waitKey(0);
```

to check whether the image is broken before I write it into the bag, however, the image shown is not broken

Anyone know what may cause the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the dataset carefully, I found its IMU and RGB-D timestamp is mismatched, so, the problem is that I forgot to write the code about timestamp correcting.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a problem with the topic names for me. Have a look at [the ROS documentation for names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names). Especially to absolute and relative names.

You are subscribing relative to your node:

```
ros::Subscriber sub_img = n.subscribe("cam0/image_raw", 100, img_callback);
```

This means, the result will be a subscription to a topic like `/your_node_name/cam0/image_raw`, which is not the topic rosbag publishes on. To subscribe absolute you need to add a `/` in front of the topic like:

```
ros::Subscriber sub_img = n.subscribe("/cam0/image_raw", 100, img_callback);
```

**Hint:** To check available topics enter

```
rostopic list
```

in a terminal after starting your replay.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, though today I finally found out my problem is caused by the mismatch of IMU and rgb-d timestamp , your suggestion is still well-worthy.